# Setup DMZ on Ubi USG-3P Router

Tags: ubiquiti

I have a few hosts that sit outside our LAN on a subnet. I'd like to move them behind our USG-3P and use the LAN2 port as a DMZ for these hosts. I don't see any way to do this in the web admin. Even NAT would be fine if I could map multiple hosts (all ports son each), ex:   map all ports on public x.x.x.x AND x.x.x.y to hosts on LAN2.